# HTML syntax highlighting in VIM on Windows 7

Tags: html, windows, vim, windows-7, command-prompt

I've set syntax highlighting on when running VIM from the command prompt. I do this by putting in the line `syntax on` in `.vimrc` file. I have also in my `.vimrc` the setting `set background=light`. And my command prompt background color is white and text color is black.

When I write html code however, when I use links, the text between my start and end tags are highlighted an opaque maroon color and I can't see the text.

How do I prevent this behavior (highlighting)?

For example,

```
<a href="next.html">Go here</a>
```

The `Go here` is highlighted and the text can't be seen.

Comment: change your background color, or use other text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change coloring for html links by adding `hi Underlined ctermbg=white` to your vimrc.